# Is new keyword required in linq when using a string

Tags: c#, linq

```
var listOfStates = from n in _storageStates
                   select n.tag;
```

If n.tag is a string do I need to use the new keyword.

```
var listOfStates = from n in _storageStates
                   select new {n.tag};
```

I would think not since string is a built in type and not a class, but I am not sure.

Comment: `new` has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: did you try them both?  that would have cleared up your question.

Comment: Have you even tried compiling both of your examples? I don't think a "Will it work if I (don't) use X" question is something you need to ask on the internet... In most cases just trying will do.

Comment: I have fixed the example so both statements will compile. I am just wondering what the difference is when compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you often see is something like:

```
var listOfStates = from n in _storageStates
                   select new { n.tag, n.foo };
```

This creates an [*anonymous type*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) which is a useful way of grouping multiple values together in a strongly-typed but somewhat ad hoc way. You *can* do it with a single value like this:

```
var listOfStates = from n in _storageStates
                   select new { n.tag };
```

but usually that makes the results *harder* to work with rather than easier.

Note that anonymous types aren't restricted to being used in LINQ, although that's probably where they're most commonly encountered. Follow the earlier MSDN link for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the new keyword. Your first example should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `new` keyword is not required as you are not actually creating a new object.  The `new` keyword can be used in the `select` statement, but it must be used as a valid expression.  Example below:

```
var listOfStates = from n in _storageStates
                   select new State(n.Tag);
```

The `new` keyword can also be used to create anonymous types using the following syntax:

```
var listOfStates = from n in _storageStates
                   select new { n.Tag };
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not required unless you're creating a new object (if you're selecting more than a single field):

```
// single field
var listOfStates = from n in _storageStates
                   select n.tag;

// multiple fields require, at least, an anonymous type
var listOfStatesAndCapitals = from n in _storageStates
                              select new { n.tag, n.capital };
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually use new in LINQ to create anonymous types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx